# Can I manipulate a Kuka kr10 with ROS?

Tags: ros, kuka

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm really new to ROS, just finished the beginner level of ROS tutorials (just had some rough ideas about topics, publishers, subscribers, etc.). My project is having this Kuka manipulator interact with human according to images captured by a Kinect sensor. So, my question is what should I look for my next stage? Learn ROS-Industrial? Gazebo simulation (I do want to do a simulation of my application but I have no idea how to do it with ROS)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271090/can-i-manipulate-a-kuka-kr10-with-ros?/) by [FloppyHank](https://answers.ros.org/users/31941/floppyhank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-09-18**:
Moving an industrial arm close to a human depending on Kinect data does not sound like a safe beginner project in robotics so maybe you should start with a less lethal setup.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-20**:
This is probably not what you want to hear @FloppyHank, but I must say that what @NEngelhard writes sounds like good advice. KR10s are not the biggest robots, but will still hurt you if something isn't working properly. I would definitely recommend starting in simulation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-20**:
As to whether the KR10 can be controlled from ROS: if we're talking KR10 Agilus with a KR C4 with RSI, then yes, that can be done.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-20**:
If you're not comfortable learning all of this, then you could perhaps look at things like Rhino, Grasshopper and the interfaces that that community created to KUKA controllers. Those are more geared towards 'performance' type installations and might be easier to set up.

**Comment by [FloppyHank](https://answers.ros.org/users/31941/floppyhank/) on 2017-09-21**:
Thanks, @gvdhoorn. I think starting from a simulation would be great, and I'm willing to learn all kinds of ROS stuffs. The problem is how should I start this simulation with ROS? I've run some tutorial simulations like baxter and turtlebot with gazebo, but can I find similar things for my kuka?

**Comment by [FloppyHank](https://answers.ros.org/users/31941/floppyhank/) on 2017-09-21**:
Don't worry @NEngelhard, I really just want to start a simulation first. And my project is not about interact with the robot by body contact. It's more like you wave to the robot and it waves back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're going to use a KUKA and you have RSI, then the ROS-Industrial components for that might be appropriate.

As to learning ROS(-Industrial): you might want to take a look at the [ros-industrial/industrial_training](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/wiki) exercises.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1